# Ant: How to write a mapper for parent folder

Tags: regex, ant, apply, mapper

Environment: Windows 2008 R2
JDK: 1.7.0_45 (x64)
Ant: 1.8.3

I'm trying to extract a few cab files. For the purpose of discussion, assume the following layout:

```
A/L/X.cab
B/M/Y.cab
C/N/Z.cab
```

What I tried:

```
<fileset id="cabfiles" dir="[correct path to parent of A,B,C]">
    <include name="**/*.cab"/>
</fileset>
<apply executable="expand" failonerror="true">
    <arg value="-r"/>
    <srcfile/>
    <arg value="-F:*"/>
    <targetfile/>
    <fileset refid="cabfiles"/>
    <regexpmapper from="(.*)\${file.separator}" to="\1"/>
</apply>
```

Going by documentation for java.util.regex.Pattern, this is expected to be a greedy pattern (I'm not an expert on that though).

My intent is to run:

```
 expand -r [absolute path to]\A\L\X.cab -F:* [absolute path to]\A\L
 expand -r [absolute path to]\B\M\Y.cab -F:* [absolute path to]\B\M
 expand -r [absolute path to]\C\N\Z.cab -F:* [absolute path to]\C\N
```

Instead, I see:

```
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'expand' with arguments:
'-r'
'[absolute path to]\A\L\X.cab'
'-F:*'
'C:\\A\X'
```

I don't wish to introduce a dependency on ant-contrib (unless that is the only way out).

- Is it possible (and logical) to pass the folder path as an argument using a single (or chained) mapper to the apply task ?
- If the cab files were downloaded into their respective parent folders after the parent folders were created (but obviously), would the mapper detect the folder as out of date w.r.t. the cab file itself and run the expand command ? Or will it just skip extracting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

Used

```
relative="true" and dir="[absolute path to]"
```

attributes on the apply task.